# docker exec TERM setting

Tags: docker

For some reason `TERM` is reset to '`dumb`' when I use 'docker exec'. The `TERM` setting in the images used is 'xterm'. When I enter the container via nsenter, the `TERM` setting is '`linux`', but that is fine.

Command to enter the container: "`docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash`".

Is this by design?

Comment: I tested with Ubuntu:latest, Debian:latest, busybox, when I run just `docker run -it Linux shell` (shell being bash or sh)  $TERM is always set to xterm

Comment: docker exec on a running nginx gives me TERM set to dumb

Comment: I notice https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9299 and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8631, so it seems by design

Comment: I like the suggestion to add -t when building the container, that works for me.

Comment: @Chris: you should answer your own question with using `-t` during build.

Answer (score 0):

I usually copy (Dockerfile -> CP) to nginx container `.profile` file with this fix:
`export TERM='xterm-256color'`